# How to locate source code of the operation ndarray[sliceobject] = ndarray?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to know the time complexity of the following Python operation
     `ndarray[sliceobject] = ndarray`.

To achieve this, I'd like to have a look to the source code but I don't know where to look at within numpy. I'm using [this repository](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy) but I can't find any documentation about the code structuration, making my research time-consuming.

I've checked the [Guide to Numpy](http://csc.ucdavis.edu/~chaos/courses/nlp/Software/NumPyBook.pdf) reference but found nothing about this concern.

I need this operation to be less than O(n), and want to ensure it's the case.

Comment: The interpreter translates that expression into `target.__setitem__(sliceobj, source`. From there the details depend on the shape (and dtype) the `source` and `target` arrays, as well as details of the `sliceobj`.  The actual copying from one array to the other is done way down in compiled `numpy` code.  I would just do some timing tests, and not try to trace the code.

Comment: It might also help to know why you need to know this.  In general with `numpy`, the distinction between operations that use compiled code, and ones that iteration in Python is more important than the `O(?)`.  `O(n)` in a Python loop will be orders of magnitude slower than a `O(n)` copy in compiled code.

Comment: Also how well do you understand `ndarray` structure?

Comment: `ndarray` is a mapping between a 1-dimensional "data buffer" and indices, from what I understood. I finally did what you said, doing timing tests and it's definetely O(n). I'll write an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did some timing tests and end up with the following plot :
[image]
It makes no doubt that `ndarray[sliceobject]=ndarray` is O(n) with n being the size of the second `ndarray`.

My test consists basically in constructing a 2-dimensional `ndarray` A, fixed size, in which is set B, a `ndarray`, with variable size. Test code is here :

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start = time.time()

step = 70000 
iterations = 10000 

nb_elements = step*iterations 
matrix_width = step
matrix_height = iterations
A = np.arange(nb_elements).reshape(matrix_height,matrix_width)

plt.xlabel('n')
plt.ylabel('Temps(secondes)')
xValues = []
yValues = []

for n in range(0,iterations):
    B = np.arange(nb_elements*(n+1),nb_elements*(n+1)+(step*  (n+1))).reshape((n+1),step)
    idx = slice(0,(n+1),1)
    start = time.time()
    A[idx] = B
    end = time.time()
    print("step : "+str(n))
    xValues.append(B.size)
    yValues.append(end-start)

plt.plot(xValues,yValues,'b.-')
plt.show()
```